# what is the difference between synchronized and static synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronized

Well, I found this question answered several times. The answer is pretty common too.
**static synchronized method** locks on the *Class* where synchronized method locks on the *instance* itself.

And two different thread of same class can not call two different **synchronized method** simultaneously. If calls then one is blocked. Same things happen for **static synchronized method**. So it seems to me that both cases are showing same usability. It will be very much helped if anyone kindly marks the difference in case of usability of these two types of methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> two different thread of same class can not call two different synchronized method simultaneously.

That is a very common misconception, but it is not always true.  Here's what is *always* true:  No two threads can be `synchronized` on the same object at the same time.

When the `synchronized` keyword is used on an instance method, the entire body of the method is synchronized on `this`.  Suppose we have a class:

```
class Foo {
    synchronized void doSomething() { ... }
    synchronized void doSomethingElse() { ... }
}
```

That's actually a shorthand way of writing this:

```
class Foo {
    void doSomething() { synchronized (this) { ... }}
    void doSomethingElse() { synchronized (this) { ... }}
}
```

Now suppose we have two instances of the class:

```
final Foo f1 = new Foo(...);
final Foo f2 = new Foo(...);
```

It is not possible for thread A to enter f1.doSomething() while thread B is in f1.doSomethingElse(), but it *is* possible for thread A to enter f1.doSomething() while thread B is in f2.doSomethingElse().  That's because f1 and f2 are *different* objects.  The `synchronized` keyword only prevents two or more threads from synchronizing on the *same* object.

The situation is slightly different for `static` methods.  This declaration:

```
class Bar {
    static synchronized void doSomething() { ... }
    static synchronized void doSomethingElse() { ... }
}
```

Is identical to this declaration:

```
class Bar {
    static void doSomething() { synchronized(Bar.class) { ... }}
    static void doSomethingElse() { synchronized(Bar.class) { ... }}
}
```

A `static` method can not synchronize on `this` because `this` is not defined for a static method.  Static methods synchronize on the class object instead.

In this case, it is *never* possible for one thread to be in Bar.doSomething() while another thread runs in Bar.doSomethingElse() because both methods synchronize on the *same* object (the Bar.class object.)

Answer (score 0):

In the code below

- No two threads will be allowed to enter the `b` method at the same time.
- No two threads will be allowed to enter the `t1.a()` method at the same time.
- One thread calling `t1.a()` will **not** interfere with another thread calling `t2.a()`.

  ```
  public class Test {

      synchronized void a() {

      }

      static synchronized void b() {

      }

      public static void main(String args[]) {
          final Test t1 = new Test();
          final Test t2 = new Test();
          // Some threads that just mess with the test objects.
          Thread test1 = new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                  while (true) {
                      t1.a();
                  }
              }
          };
          Thread test2 = new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                  while (true) {
                      t2.b();
                  }
              }
          };
          Thread test3 = new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                  while (true) {
                      t1.a();
                      t1.b();
                      t2.a();
                      t2.b();
                  }
              }
          };
          test1.start();
          test2.start();
          test3.start();
      }
  }
  ```